# using char or varchar on MySQL Table with 2 billion rows

Tags: mysql, performance, types

We are working with a table of +2 billion rows in MySQL 8.x and need extend the length of a character field. Dedicated server +300G RAM.

One column is of datatype char(10) and is the part of a two column primary key with various constraints to other tables. This column is the unique identifier across several large tables.

Now there we need to extend it to 14 characters as some rare data requires it. About 95% right now are 8 characters long.

What will be faster, Varchar(14) or Char(14) considering that we need to change accross various tables with indexes on them. In total we have about 4 billion datasets. And only the storage would increase by +10gig uncompressed if using char(14)

Comment: Are the `CHAR(10)` values using all 10 characters in the existing data? If not, what is the average length?

Comment: Nice question, I hope this discussion can help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1915

Comment: If they're usually less than 9 characters, you'll actually reduce the size by changing to `VARCHAR`. Also, there's no space difference between `VARCHAR(14)` and `VARCHAR(255)`. They both use 1 byte for the length and only as many data bytes as needed.

Comment: Use `VARCHAR(30)` so you won't have repeat this task if it happens again.  Use `CHAR` _only_ for truly fixed-length columns.  It will take a lot of downtime.  The FKs _may_ trouble.

Comment: "4 billion datasets" -- I hope you mean "rows", not `DATABASEs` or `TABLEs`.  Else we need to have a different discussion!